# Zoom issue in MKMapView when it is fully zoomed out

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, zooming

I am zooming out the map on the click of the button.

So when the map is fully zoomed out and if I try to again zoom out it then it crashes while setting the region.

Not sure but, Is there any way out to detect if the map has reached it maximum zoom limit?

Here is my code to zoom out the map

```
-(void)setZoomLevelForNoPicksCurrentLocationAt:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)currentCoordinate{
 MKCoordinateSpan span;
 MKCoordinateRegion region;
 region.center = currentCoordinate;
 span.latitudeDelta =self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta *2;
 span.longitudeDelta =self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta *2;
 region.span = span;
 [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];  
 [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
}
```

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Please find the crash log

> > *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region center:+38.82259098, -67.50000000 span:+307.41536753, +450.00000000'
> >     *** Call stack at first throw:
> >     (
> >         0   CoreFoundation                      0x013c8be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
> >         1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0151d5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
> >         2   CoreFoundation                      0x013c8b21 -[NSException raise] + 17
> >         3   XXXapp                             0x000ab237 -[MapViewController setZoomLevelForNoPicksCurrentLocationAt:] + 312

Comment: Can you please post a crash message in console & stack-trace here?

Comment: I have stated the reason for crash.. That the map is zoomed out to maximum extent and now again I am calling the above function which again tries to zoom out the map, causing a crash.. Please find the crash log in the question

Comment: As @iamsult indicates, the deltas are out of range.  Latitude delta must be from 0 to 180 and longitude delta must be from 0 to 360.  Before calling setRegion, adjust the deltas as needed.  Also, the call to regionThatFits is pointless.

Comment: Thanks Anna. Got the maximum range from googling. So solved the issue.. But if it was a as answer I would have definately voted it up..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The minimum span value u can provide is 0.0 . At run-time the value of span is getting negative which causes the crash. Just hard cord and try and put a nslog to monitor the value of span. The maximum span value is 180.0 above that will result in crash.

Comment: I have tried checking out by putting NSLog(). But as you can see in the code that the value of span in increased by twice its current. So initially its 0.87 then it works fine till 103.00 but when I doubles to 306.00 it crashes.. so the value of span can be for sure more than 0.0. May be you have typo maximum instead of minimum :P

Comment: Also you can see the span value in the crash log added below the question.. Do you have any idea how much maximum can the span be set?

Comment: sorry for typo. Max value for span is 180.0.

Comment: you were correct.. But as per the question you can see that the issue is not because of going below.. but it is because of going above 180.As such I have solved the issue. But if you could add the same on your answer I can get the reason to select your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I just added following checks to deltas calculation that prevent crashes on applying region:

```
//calculate deltas
double deltaLat = fabs(max_lat - min_lat) * 2;
if (deltaLat > 180) deltaLat = 180;

double deltaLong = fabs(max_long - min_long) * 2;
if (deltaLong>360) deltaLong = 360;
```

So the region delta latitude can not be more then 180 and longitude more then 360.

Comment: This actually is the better answer. The first (accepted) one is only partially correct!

Answer (score 0):

Solution in **Swift 3.0** after a few trial and error tests.

Here is how I calculated my deltas:

```
let distanceLat = min(abs((currentLatitude! - pinLatitude) * 5), 180)
let distanceLon = min(abs((currentLongitude! - pinLongitude) * 5), 180)
```

The *5 is arbitrary, feel free to change it as you will.